# jquery datepicker - add class to first 17 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a way to give a class to the first 17 days on a jquery datepicker calendar?

I have tried this but it just seems to add the class to every day...

```
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            return [true, 'myClass'];
        }
        return [false, ''];
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I've managed to nearly get it with the following code:

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {

    if (date <= new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+17) && date >= new Date() ) {
        return [true, 'myClass'];
    }

    return [true, ''];

}
```

The only problem is that it doesn't give the class to todays date. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

maybe something like:

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
   var today = new Date(), maxDate;
   today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   maxDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 17);
   if (date <= maxDate && date >= today ) {
      return [true, 'myClass'];
   }
   return [true, ''];
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/625/)

Comment: Hi... that's close, but it actually adds the class to the first 17 days of each month... What I want is only the first 17 days after and including today.